# yii2 server function returns empty result on request from my Angular controller

Tags: php, json, angularjs, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have my Angular `$http.post` request. The server returns response in JSON format. According to [yii2-cookbook](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/response-formats.md):

```
public function actionIndex() {
   \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $id = 2015;
    return $id;
}
```

But this function doesn't return anything:

```
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

One more example:

```
public function actionIndex() {
   \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $id = 2015;
    echo $id; // echo instead of return
}
```

Now there is some data in response:

```
Content-Length:4
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Why does the first example with return statement might not work?

My controller on UI:

```
var request = $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/resume/save',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
        myData: $scope.myData
    }
});
request.success(function(id) {
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: I tested it locally and it works just fine. Can you post your complete controller's code? There must be something there that's interfering with the normal behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code should work:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;    
    $id = 2015;    
    return $id;
}
```

I've tested it with jQuery ajax request:

```
<?= Html::a('asd', '/', ['class'=>'asd']); ?>
<?php $this->registerJs("$('a.asd').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/catalog/index',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
})");
```

And got correct response in console.

Also, note, that you have to send **CSRF** token for post requests in Yii2. So, you need to add it to request headers. Here is an example for Angular 1.4:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
}]);   

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {            
    var request = $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/data/test',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
            myData : $scope.myData
        }
    });    
    request.success(function (id) {
        console.log(id);
    });          
});
```